# Why should i use url.openStream instead of of url.getContent?

Tags: java

I would like to retrieve the content of a url.
Similar to pythons:

```
html_content = urllib.urlopen("http://www.test.com/test.html").read()
```

In examples( [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/GetContentfromaURL.htm) ) you see very often the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.test.com/test.html");
String foo = (String) url.getContent();
```

The Description of getContent is the following:

```
Gets the contents of this URL. This method is a shorthand for: openConnection().getContent()
Returns: the contents of this URL.
```

In my opinion that should work perfectly fine.
Buuut obviously this code doesnt work, because it raises an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Obviously it returns an inputStream.

**So i ask myself: what's the purpose of this function which isn't doing what it is seems to do?
And why is no hint for quirks it in the documentation?
And why did i saw it in several examples?**

Or am i getting this wrong?

The suggested solution ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523730/problem-in-getting-url-getcontent)) is to use url.openStream() and then read the Stream.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you said, documentation says that `URL.getContent()` is a shortcut for `openConnection().getContent()` so we need to look at [the documentation for `URLConnection.getContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContent%28%29).

We can see that this returns an `Object` the type of which is determined by the the `content-type` header field of the response.  This type determines the [`ContentHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ContentHandler.html) that will be used. So a `ContentHandler` converts data based on its  MIME type to the appropriate class of Java Object.

In other words the type of Object you get will depend on the content served.  For example, it wouldn't make sense to return a `String` if the MIME type was `image/png`.

This is why in the example code you link to at java2s.com they check the class of the returned Object:

```
try {
  URL u = new URL("http://www.java2s.com");
  Object o = u.getContent();
  System.out.println("I got a " + o.getClass().getName());
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.err.println(ex);
}
```

So you can say `String foo = (String) url.getContent();` if you know your `ContentHandler` will return a `String`.

There are default content handlers defined in the `sun.net.www.content` package but as you can see they are returning streams for you.

You could create your own `ContentHandler` that does return a `String` but it will probably be easier just to read the Stream as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand what "Content" means. You expected it to return a String containing the HTML, but it returns a HttpInputStream. Why? Because the requested URL is a html webpage. Another valid URL might be `http://www.google.com/logo.png`. This URL doesn't contain String content. It is an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Resources.toString(URL, Charset)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html#toString(java.net.URL,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) method to more easily read a URL to a string.