# Assign String-Data to a URL-Object

Tags: java, string, url

Is it possible to assign string-data to a `java.net.URL`?

I'm using an API who's method only accept an URL-Parameter. But i already have the content.

```
String content = "some text data";
URL url = createURLWithContent(content);
MyApi.handleContent( url );
```

the `createURLWithContent()`-Method should create `URL`-object that containing the data from `content`, so when `URL.getContent()` is called, the String (or a Stream containing the String) is returned.

I think I've seen something like this years ago.

Comment: Please refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795331/why-should-i-use-url-openstream-instead-of-of-url-getcontent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the content to a file then provide a `file:` URL, e.g.

```
public static URL createURLWithContent(String content) throws IOException {
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("UrlContent", null);
    tempFile.toFile().deleteOnExit();
    Files.writeString(tempFile, content);
    return tempFile.toUri().toURL();
}
```

This will return a URL like this:

```
file:/C:/path/to/temp/UrlContent5767435257817348076.tmp
```

If your program is long-running, you should handle the deletion of the temporary file yourself, after the API call, rather than rely on `deleteOnExit()`.

If you don't want the content on disk, you could alternatively implement your own in-memory [`URLStreamHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html), and specify it when creating the URL using the [`URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file, URLStreamHandler handler)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String-java.net.URLStreamHandler-) constructor. This is a lot more involved and beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Dear , I was wondering , your answer because of you are not understanding the question as i think , If i am wrong , please  correct me , Thanks , I'm not trying to down vote , because your advice is very helpfully to me as well

Comment: @DulajKulathunga Question includes a 3 line code example. In that code, the `MyApi.handleContent` method is from an API that cannot be modified. OP is asking how to implement the `URL createURLWithContent(String content)` method, and this answer shows one way to do that. In what way do you believe I'm misunderstanding that?

Comment: close enough to what i expected. I thought it would be possible to create a string with something like `data::url-encoded-data` and then use it as a url. But your suggestion with URLStreamHandler sounds also good and safe, if I don't want to use a file. Maybe I will to use this solution cause my app is running on a server and i'm not sure, if the tempFile is deleted, when the garbage collector destroys the file.

Comment: @D.Walz `deleteOnExit()` truly means that, i.e. that the file is deleted when the JVM exits. For a webapp, it can be a very long time before that happens, which is why I said that you should handle the deletion of the temporary file yourself, i.e. after `MyApi.handleContent( url )` returns.