# Connect to Car2Go API

Tags: java, url

Trying to connect to Car2Go API. I have the authentication key but instead of having an InputStream reference when writing the code below, I have a no-content-type error, as if I had no data coming from the car2Go API.

```
String url ="http://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc=ulm&oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key";

Object resultat = null;
try {
    resultat = new URL(url).getContent();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String finalResult = resultat.toString();
System.out.println(finalResult);
return finalResult;
```

Comment: What do you get if you just curl the URL from the command line?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by curl from the command line, I am not sure what you mean ?

Comment: I might add that I have not been given any password by Car2Go, just the consumer key

Comment: I mean what happens if you use some other method of fetching the URL, outside of java code.  curl is a common unix command-line tool for doing exactly that.  If you are on a unix-like system, you can just run "curl http://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc=ulm&oauth_consumer_key=YOUR_OAUTH_KEY" from the command line.  I don't know a windows equivalent off the top of my head.  The point is to isolate whether it is a problem with the API, or a problem with your Java code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in getting url.getContent()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523730/problem-in-getting-url-getcontent)

Answer (score 0):

URL.getContent() [probably does not do what you think it does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getContent()).  It expects the web server to have an appropriate Content-Type header, and then attempts to coerce the HTML returned from the URL into a corresponding Java object.  The error indicates that the Car2Go API might not include a Content-Type header, so getContent() doesn't know what sort of Java object to turn it into.

Regardless, your actual goal in the code snippet appears to be to retrieve the HTML text served at the URL as a `java.lang.String`.  In that case, you should use the `openStream` method as suggested in [Marcelo's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6523910/83715).  Here is your code snippet, re-written to use URL.openStream():

```
String url ="http://www.car2go.com/api/v2.1/vehicles?loc=ulm&oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
    InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String finalResult = sb.toString();
System.out.println(finalResult);
return finalResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Car2Go allows you to specify the format of the return, which might help.  For example if you include a parameter of `format=json` you'll get JSON.  You'll probably want to confirm that you actually have successfully connected to the Car2Go API and that your data request was successful by checking the status code.

https://github.com/eebbesen/car2gosling is a Java client that connects to the Car2Go API and retrieves locations.  Full disclosure: I wrote it.